# When does automatic partial reindexing actually run in Magento EE 1.13?

Tags: magento, indexing, magento-1.13

Magento 1.13 added partial indexing for most indexes along with the ability to defer the indexing process to a cron job that runs asynchronously.

My question then is, is there an existing cron job that does this or is this something I have to set up myself?

The documentation is not clear on this:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee113-indexing#reindex-options

> - **Update when scheduled** to schedule reindexing using your Magento cron job.
> - The change occurs either within the minute or according to your cron job schedule.

This leads me to believe it's an existing process that runs every time the cron runs.

I see the index cleaner schedule, but that only appears to clear out old records in the change log tables. It does not seem to actually do any indexing.

I can't seem to find a cron job in core code that runs these indexes.

Answer (score 9):

I think I found it. enterprise_refresh_index

```
<enterprise_refresh_index>
    <schedule>
        <cron_expr>always</cron_expr>
    </schedule>
    <run>
        <model>enterprise_index/observer::refreshIndex</model>
    </run>
</enterprise_refresh_index>
```

---

```
public function refreshIndex(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule $schedule)
{
    /** @var $helper Enterprise_Index_Helper_Data */
    $helper = Mage::helper('enterprise_index');

    /** @var $lock Enterprise_Index_Model_Lock */
    $lock   = Enterprise_Index_Model_Lock::getInstance();

    if ($lock->setLock(self::REINDEX_FULL_LOCK)) {

        /**
         * Workaround for fatals and memory crashes: Invalidating indexers that are in progress
         * Successful lock setting is considered that no other full reindex processes are running
         */
        $this->_invalidateInProgressIndexers();

        $client = Mage::getModel('enterprise_mview/client');
        try {

            //full re-index
            $inactiveIndexes = $this->_getInactiveIndexersByPriority();
            $rebuiltIndexes = array();
            foreach ($inactiveIndexes as $inactiveIndexer) {
                $tableName  = (string)$inactiveIndexer->index_table;
                $actionName = (string)$inactiveIndexer->action_model->all;
                $client->init($tableName);
                if ($actionName) {
                    $client->execute($actionName);
                    $rebuiltIndexes[] = $tableName;
                }
            }

            //re-index by changelog
            $indexers = $helper->getIndexers(true);
            foreach ($indexers as $indexerName => $indexerData) {
                $indexTable = (string)$indexerData->index_table;
                $actionName = (string)$indexerData->action_model->changelog;
                $client->init($indexTable);
                if (isset($actionName) && !in_array($indexTable, $rebuiltIndexes)) {
                    $client->execute($actionName);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $lock->releaseLock(self::REINDEX_FULL_LOCK);
            throw $e;
        }

        $lock->releaseLock(self::REINDEX_FULL_LOCK);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This runs "always" on every cron execution. It runs full reindexes for the indexes that need and and processes the changelog for those that don't.